# filter INFO logs to Appender file except a specific class

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I'm using Log4j and i want to write from class Main to log file,
the issue is that the log gets all the INFO logs from other classes
along with the class i wanted to write to the file.
for example :

```
log4j.xml    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="fileAppenderMain1" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="file" value="logs/main1/main1.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10240KB" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">     
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <logger name="Main1.class" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderMain1" />
    </logger>


    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderMain1"></appender-ref>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>


    public class Main1 {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main1.class);

    public void log()  {

        log.info("Hello world");

     }
    }

    public class Main2 {    

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main2.class);

    public void log()   {

        log.info("Hello world");

     }
    }

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args)   {

        Main1 main1=new Main1();
        Main2 main2=new Main2();
        main1.log();
        main2.log();


     }
    }
```

output to file:

```
12 May 2015 12:59:09  INFO Main1 - Hello world    
12 May 2015 12:59:09  INFO Main2 - Hello world
```

i want to log only "Main1" logs

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the the root logger to info as well.

You can change it to WARN , ERROR , FATAL if you want to see your Main1's info logs alone and the rest from warn and above.

As such:

```
<root>
        <priority value="WARN"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderMain1"></appender-ref>
</root>
```

---

Updated:

If you want Main1.class 's logs and no other logs you can use

```
<root>
        <priority value="OFF"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderMain1"></appender-ref>
</root>
```

Comment: i have Error , Warn and Info Logs in my application, it wont help me.

Comment: You said "i want to log only "Main1" logs". Keep the Main1 info logs, and for the rest of the application (root logger) keep the default level you want. I assumed you wanted info for main1 and for the others, higher level. You can go with the highest, like fatal to filter out the messages. But that only makes sense for development mode. If that doesn't help you, your question is not specific enough.

Comment: Hi,sorry for the misleading questions. i need it for prod mode. thanks

Comment: I updated the answer to fit the logging only for Main1.class logs.